# DB の接続先はいつも一緒か？

Tags: sql

SQLで 接続先のホスト名は

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

で 取得できるようですが

接続するサーバーはみな一緒なのではないですか？

Comment: いくつかのご質問で [sql] タグをつけてらっしゃいますが、細かいクエリの文法は RDBMS について異なることがあるので、お使いの RDBMS についてもタグや本文に記載があると嬉しいです。（他のご質問的に MySQL でしょうか。）

Answer (score 1):

文字通り自分が接続しているデータベースのホスト名を返してくれるものですが、
DBが単一サーバ内に置かれていてその単一のサーバのDBに対してきちんと接続先を指定していればもちろん一緒になります。

ただし、その前提が崩れるインフラ構成をとることもできます。
例えばリードレプリカを用意して、DNSラウンドロビンやロードバランサで接続するサーバを完全ランダムで接続先を変えるということができます。
その場合に、ランダムだけど今接続しているのはどのサーバになのか？という情報を取ることができます。

とはいえ、サーバによって動作を変えたりすることはないです。あくまで環境の変数なのでデバッグやログのための変数と思ってもらって、シンプルなアプリケーションではあまり使われない変数ではあります。

Comment: データベースはミラーリングされているとおもうのですが移された場合値に変化はありますか ？

Comment: ミラーリングしているので、DBのデータには変化はないです。質問中にある環境変数と呼ばれるものはもちろん違います。